# How to specify the Lead owner when creating with REST API?

Tags: rest-api, api, standard-objects, record

I searched through the documentation and it seems Lead creation is done by sending a hash of attributes. How do you specify the Lead owner? By email? User ID? Is there any documentation?

Comment: OwnerId field in lead is not a hash field on lead, but an 18 digit User ID. WHich is the primary key in user table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify by username, email, Id, and for queues, Id and Name.

---

```
{ 
  "LastName": "Demo", 
  "Company": "Demo", 
  "Owner": {
    "attributes": { "type": "User" },
    "Username": "login@domain.com" 
  }
}
```

---

```
{ 
  "LastName": "Demo", 
  "Company": "Demo", 
  "Owner": {
    "attributes": { "type": "User" },
    "Email": "login@domain.com" 
  }
}
```

---

```
{ 
  "LastName": "Demo", 
  "Company": "Demo", 
  "OwnerId": "005.."
}
```

---

```
{ 
  "LastName": "Demo", 
  "Company": "Demo", 
  "OwnerId": "00G.."
}
```

---

```
{ 
  "LastName": "Demo", 
  "Company": "Demo", 
  "Owner": {
    "attributes": { "type": "Group" },
    "Name": "Queue Name" 
  }
}
```

---

You can get the User ID (005...) or Queue ID (00G...) from the User or Group tables, respectively.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. I looked through the REST API doc (https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/216/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/api_rest.pdf), but did not see this info. Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: @BSeven I would have been willing to bet this is in the docs somewhere, but I can't seem to find it now. The closest I've gotten is [this doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_upsert.htm), but I'm not sure it explains things in detail enough (I don't think it does). At any rate, I hope you find this information useful.

Comment: I get `ERROR: JSON_PARSER_ERROR: Cannot deserialize instance of <unknown> from null value null or request may be missing a required field` when using Email or Username. Are you sure it works?

Comment: @BSeven Yes, all of the above forms work, as I actually tested a number of combinations and posted those that worked here (with redacted information, of course). The JSON has to be perfect, though, or you can easily get that error message.

Comment: Is there any special reason that `attributes` and `type` are lowercase? Are they case sensitive?

Comment: @BSeven The documentation always shows them written as such, so that's how I've always used them. I just tested this, though, and found that `attributes` is apparently case-insensitive, but `type` is case-sensitive. To be safe, consider always using lowercase for these two attributes. Deviating from the documentation is not advised.

Comment: Thanks for this, looks like it also needs the `ViewAllRecords` permission for users in order to be able to do this.